# offset to anthor column and stop when condition is meet

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a dataset is 5x5.

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1
```

I want to move my selection to the cell is 1.

I wrote a macro, but I can only ask it to stop when the cell is 1.

I dont how to tell the excel shift to another row when after 5 column passes.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

thx.

```
Sub macro1()
'
Range("A2").Select
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping through all the cells, you can Find what you are looking for. From your code provided, it looks like your data starts at A2.

```
Sub Find_One()
    Dim rng As Range, oC As Range, s As String
    s = 1    ' this is what you want to find
    Set rng = Range("A2:E6")

    Set oC = rng.Find(what:=s, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not oC Is Nothing Then
        Cells(oC.Row, oC.Column).Select
    Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

If "1" is going to show up more than once, then this code would work for you.

```
Sub Select_1()
    Dim FrstRng As Range
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set FrstRng = Range("A2:E6")

    For Each c In FrstRng.Cells

        If c = 1 Then
            If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, c)    'adds to the range
            Else
                Set UnionRng = c
            End If
        End If

    Next c

    UnionRng.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub macro1()
For Each cell In Range("A1:E5")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```